# how do I plot a standard deviation error line?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

Using scipy I can plot the standard deviation line. How do I duplicate that same line 95% above and another one 95% below.

See the two images below of what I mean:

[image]

[image]

My code:

```
import datetime as date
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import datetime
from scipy import stats

Ins_Name = "EURUSD=X"
#Ins_Name = "AAPL"
df = yf.download(Ins_Name,'2019-05-01','2020-01-03')

df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df['date_ordinal'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).apply(lambda date: date.toordinal())
DateVariance = [datetime.date(2019, 5, 1), datetime.date(2020, 1, 3)]

x_reg = df.date_ordinal
y_reg = df.Close
slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(x_reg, y_reg)
print("slope: %f    intercept: %f     STD Error: %f" % (slope, intercept, std_err))

sns.set()
#plt.figure(figsize=(26, 10))
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,7))
ax = plt.plot(x_reg,intercept + slope*x_reg, color='b')
#ax = sns.lmplot('date_ordinal', 'Close', data=df, fit_reg=True, aspect=2, ) #Scatter PLot
ax = sns.regplot(data=df,x='date_ordinal',y=df.Close,ci=1,fit_reg=False,scatter_kws={"color": "red"}, line_kws={"color": "black"}, marker='x') #scatterplot
#sns.jointplot('date_ordinal', df.Close, data=df, kind="reg",ylim=[1.089,1.15],xlim=DateVariance, height=12,color='red',scatter_kws={"color": "red"}, line_kws={"color": "black"})

ax.set_xlabel('Interval', fontsize=25)
ax.set_xlim(DateVariance)
ax.set_ylabel('Price', fontsize=25)
ax.set_title('Mean reversion of ' + Ins_Name + ' Close Prices',fontsize= 45,color='black')
new_labels = [datetime.date.fromordinal(int(item)) for item in ax.get_xticks()]
ax.set_xticklabels(new_labels)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the function `stats.linregress()` is not what you want here. It only returns the uncertainty on the slope and not the y-intercept, which, if I understand your question, is what you want.

I would use `scipy.optimize.curve_fit()` like below:

```py
import datetime as date
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

def fline(x, *par):
    return par[0] + par[1]*x

Ins_Name = "EURUSD=X"
#Ins_Name = "AAPL"
df = yf.download(Ins_Name,'2019-05-01','2020-01-03')

df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df['date_ordinal'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).apply(lambda date: date.toordinal())
DateVariance = [datetime.date(2019, 5, 1), datetime.date(2020, 1, 3)]

x_reg = df.date_ordinal
x_trans = x_reg - x_reg[0]

y_reg = df.Close
pi = [1.1, -0.0001] # initial guess. Could use linregress to get these values
# Perform curve fitting here
popt, cov = curve_fit(fline, x_trans, y_reg, p0=pi) # returns the values and the covariance (error) matrix
yInterceptSigma = np.sqrt(cov[0,0])
print(x_reg)
print(x_reg - x_reg[0])
print(popt)
print(cov)

sns.set()
#plt.figure(figsize=(26, 10))
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,7))
ax = plt.plot(x_reg, fline(x_trans, *popt), color='b')
# +/- 2sigma gives ~95% CI
plt.plot(x_reg, fline(x_trans, *[popt[0] + 2 * yInterceptSigma, popt[1]]), '--b') # +2sigma on the yintercept
plt.plot(x_reg, fline(x_trans, *[popt[0] - 2 * yInterceptSigma, popt[1]]), '--b') # -2sigma on teh yintercept
#ax = sns.lmplot('date_ordinal', 'Close', data=df, fit_reg=True, aspect=2, ) #Scatter PLot
ax = sns.regplot(data=df,x='date_ordinal',y=df.Close,ci=1,fit_reg=False,scatter_kws={"color": "red"}, line_kws={"color": "black"}, marker='x') #scatterplot
#sns.jointplot('date_ordinal', df.Close, data=df, kind="reg",ylim=[1.089,1.15],xlim=DateVariance, height=12,color='red',scatter_kws={"color": "red"}, line_kws={"color": "black"})

ax.set_xlabel('Interval', fontsize=25)
ax.set_xlim(DateVariance)
ax.set_ylabel('Price', fontsize=25)
ax.set_title('Mean reversion of ' + Ins_Name + ' Close Prices',fontsize= 45,color='black')
new_labels = [datetime.date.fromordinal(int(item)) for item in ax.get_xticks()]
ax.set_xticklabels(new_labels)

plt.show()
```

Which gives the following plot:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the comment. This is not working though. My chart values squash into a single line with the covariance error being placed way out of range above price.

Comment: Okay, there was an issue I was misunderstanding with how the dates were being treated in the fit. What I did (edited my original post) was transform the days from `[737180, 737181, ...]` to `[0, 1, 2, ...]` and then did the fit, so the y-intercept and error were actually what you would expect from the plot. Before the fit was getting messed up because the initial guess was so bad due to this shift in the axis.

Comment: Works. Thank you alexpiers. Now to go through and figure out how it works :)